# Dynamic laravel echo listeners

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm using Laravel echo with Livewire like this.

```
protected function getListeners()
{
    $listeners=[];
    if($this->posts !== null)
    foreach($this->posts as $post){
        $listeners["echo:update-post-$post->id,UpdatePostEvent"]='updatePost';
    }

    return $listeners;

}
```

when the event runs. All users who listening to that channel got this error:

```
Undefined array key "echo:update-post-1,UpdatePostEvent".
```

Anyone know why is this happening?

Comment: Are you sure its from that function?

Comment: I have the same problem right now. Did you solve it somehow?